# regex for username validation php

Tags: php, regex, validation

I am trying to make username validation with regex and PHP.
The requirements are:

- No spaces
- Only lowercase letters and digits
- No special characters except (.),(-),(_) and the user cannot use two or more special characters together
- username should not start with special characters
- minimum length 6 and maximum 25

this is what I've done so far
`/^[a-z0-9]{6,25}\S*$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there can be no special char at the end of the username, use

```js
^(?=.{6,25}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*$
```

Else, if there can be a special char at the end:

```js
^(?=.{6,25}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*[._-]?$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9PlG0h/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{6,25}$)` - 6 to 25 chars other than line break chars allowed in the string
- `[a-z0-9]+` - one or more digits or lowercase letters
- `(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of a `.`, `_` or `-` followed with one or more digits or lowercase letters
- `[._-]?` - an optional `.`, `_` or `-`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, also I forgot to mention the username should not consist of only numbers how to add this? and where can I learn more about regex codes. thank you.

Comment: @Tanuj1899 No numbers only requirement is easy to implement with a negative lookahead: `^(?!\d+$)(?=.{6,25}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*$`

Comment: I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.

Comment: @Tanuj1899 I also posted [some regex articles](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/posts) and am planning to start a Youtube channel with some quick regex demos. I will let you know when I start it.

Comment: Thank you for all the resources, I am just getting started with regex. Your channel will be very helpful for me and all others seeking help.

Comment: @Tanuj1899 Hi, I have started uploading some [regex videos on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFeq5T-LNtqpVrn_rcJ9hFw), feel free to check them out if you want to learn more about regex. As I am a novice in Youtubing, I'd be grateful for any suggestions.